# for the placequeen function, how does the board.append and board.remove work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, n-queens

""" Adapted from http://www.prasannatech.net/2012/07/eight-queens-python.html
Author: S.Prasanna

```
There are many other solutions to this problem available online. This one 
is quite easy to understand.
Make sure to credit other peoples code when used - and it is not acceptable to use 
other peoples code as the entire solution for your assignments!!!
```

"""

`board = [] size = 8`

```
#A function which checks if a particular row and col is dangerous (i.e.,
#queen could be taken if placed there)
def danger(row, col):
    """ Return if there is a danger by placing queen in
        a given row, col
    """
    for (i, j) in board:
        if row == i: return True
        if col == j: return True
        if abs(row - i) == abs(col - j): return True
    return False

#A function which calculates the whole solution    
def placequeen(row):
    #If row is bigger than size, we've finished - so print answer
    if row > size:
        print(board)
    #If size <= row we still have more to place        
    else:
        #try placing queen
        for col in range(1, size + 1):
            #is it safe?
            if not danger(row, col):
                board.append((row, col))
                placequeen(row + 1)
                board.remove((row,col))

#Run the main method, starts by plaing the first queen
placequeen(1)
```

why board.append is followed by board.remove? doesn't this do nothing to the list?

Comment: Note that a function call occurs between the addition and the removal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that yes, it does undo what it has just done, but the placequeen in between the two will print out every solution in between. So a queen is placed on the board with board.append((row, col)), every solution for that configuration is then printed out because the function is recursive, and then the queen is removed so that the other options can be tried.